# CentOS8/RedHat8 - Disable AppStream modules when custom compiling?

Tags: php, apache, compilation, centos8

This is a general question regarding AppStream modules in CentOS/RedHat 8. If we are custom compiling apps such as Apache or PHP, should we disable the AppStream module for that app? I don't seem to be finding any direct reference to this in documentation. Is there any benefit and/or necessity? Thanks!

Comment: this question is probably more likely to get a good answer on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which software you're going to install, you even might not be able to disable AppStream modules (due to dependencies or because you need a newer version of a library or so).

Whether AppStream modules are enabled or not doesn't matter except you're installing packages from such AppStream modules – especially if they overlap with your custom software: Imagine you're installing `httpd` from an AppStream module and you're also compiling it yourself using the same paths…the next `dnf update` will replace your binaries with that ones in the updated RPM package from the AppStream module.

Answer (score 0):

the URL for CentOS Repo has changed to "https://vault.centos.org". For Example:
baseurl=https://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/BaseOS/$basearch/os/

Update the repo files accordingly, run "yum update/ dnf update:".and it should work fine.